# How can I fetch next n rows after a particular column value in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a result set from which I want to get next n rows (or previous n rows) after (before) the row that matches a particular cell value.

So for example, here is my data:

```
A    B   C
1   10   100
2   20   200
3   30   300
4   40   400
5   50   500
6   60   600
```

I am interested to get next 3 rows after the row where C=300, including C=300 row, so my output should be

```
 A    B   C
3   30   300
4   40   400
5   50   500
6   60   600
```

With `FETCH` and `OFFSET`, you need to know the exact position number of the row, here I have to search where the data condition, i.e C=300 resides so I cannot assume that it will be the 3rd row.

```
select *
from table
order by C asc
```

Comment: Just confirming... this cannot be done in whichever programming language you are using along with Postgres? If you have a query set in that instance (i.e. In Python, Java, whatever), all you need to do is loop it and gather the needed values based on a simple loop counter. Or you can reference the `id - pk` when that is found, and then count up 3 `ids` and gather those rows specifically (this latter method will be better with algorithmic complexity)

Comment: @ViaTech: Can be (using python) but was trying to see a way in sql.

Comment: I will hold off posting an answer until an SQL 'guru' sees this post, however, in my instances it has generally been easier to handle filtering more complex data using the real programming language as opposed to more a complex SQL query

Comment: In SQL there are no *before* or *after* as long as a sort order is not defined. Provide info about it.

Comment: Rows are not ordered in SQL, so you need to do something like `SELECT a, b, c FROM table WHERE c > some_value ORDER BY c ASC LIMIT some_value;` Then based on the results of the query you can determine the `WHERE c > some_value` for the next n rows. The issue is dealing with duplicate values for `c` (sometimes handled by using a sequential key column - in your case `a` may serve this purpose).

Comment: @klin Okay, so added a sort order as `order by C asc`. See my edits.

Comment: Well, add `where c >= 300` before `order` and `limit 4` at the end and the problem resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've got a table named sample, you could use a nested query and window functions to solve your issue, something like:

```
select * 
from (
      select *, lag(c,3) over(order by c asc) as three_back  
      from sample
      where sample.c >= 300
 ) t 

where coalesce(three_back,300) = 300
```

Answer (score 0):

If your rows are ordered by the column value you are interested in then

```
  SELECT *
    FROM table_name 
   WHERE column_name >= x
ORDER BY column_name
   LIMIT n
```

should do it. If not you’ll have to get creative

If your column values are unique and you want to order by another value then

```
  SELECT *
    FROM table_name
   WHERE other_column >= (
    SELECT other_column
      FROM table_name
      WHERE column_value = x
         )
ORDER BY other_column
   LIMIT n
```

If your column values are not unique you can

```
SELECT MIN(other_column)
```

in the inner select. This finds the first occurrence (using the other column to order by), and then retrieves the next (n - 1) rows